# How do I skip every other paragraph <p> with an anchor <a> that contains a certain class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def scrape_data_from_url(url):
    try:
        # Send a GET request to fetch the webpage content
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()

        # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        # Extract the desired data from the webpage
        # Modify this part to suit your specific data extraction needs
        data = {}
        data['title'] = soup.title.text.strip()
        
        paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
        for idx, p in enumerate(paragraphs, start=1):
            data[f'paragraph_{idx}'] = p.text.strip()

        return data

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while scraping {url}: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    webUrl = requests.get('http://www.ufcstats.com/statistics/events/completed')
    print("result code: " + str(webUrl.status_code))
    data = webUrl.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    links = [table['href'] for table in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
    del links[0:6]
    del links[24:40]

    # Initialize a list to store the scraped data from each URL
    scraped_data_list = []

    for url in links:
        scraped_data = scrape_data_from_url(url)
        if scraped_data:
            scraped_data_list.append(scraped_data)

    # Create a pandas DataFrame from the scraped data
    df = pd.DataFrame(scraped_data_list)

    # Remove the first column (title) from the DataFrame
    df.drop(columns=['title'], inplace=True)

    # Print the DataFrame (optional)
    print(df)

    # Save the DataFrame to a CSV file (optional)
    df.to_csv('scraped_data.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code is leaving blank values in my CSV file for every paragraph `<p>` that contains an anchor `<a>` with class `"b-flag b-flag_style_bordered"`.

I want it to instead skip every OTHER paragraph `<p>` that contains an anchor `<a>` with class `"b-flag b-flag_style_bordered"`, and not include any cell in the csv for those paragraphs rather than include a blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could select your elements more specific in example with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and exclude these with class `b-flag_style_bordered`.

To select the `p`:

```
soup.select('p:has(a:not(.b-flag_style_bordered))')
```

or just the `a`:

```
soup.select('p>a:not(.b-flag_style_bordered)')
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.ufcstats.com/event-details/4c27ca8c8481f79a').text)

soup.select('p:has(a:not(.b-flag_style_bordered))')
```